# How do I compare 2 objects if they have three values to be tested against?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a less than and equal operator function for a class object.

The three variables that are apart of the class are

```
string firstName;
string LastName;
int age;
```

To compare them, I wrote this operator function:

```
bool person::operator < (person b)
{
    if (firstName < b.firstName && lastName < b.lastName && age < b.age)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

However, my code doesn't work and I don't understand why.

When comparing the objects, priority goes to lastName, firstName, then age.

So,
Bill Gates 43 would be technically less than Bill Gates 44.

I hope that is clear enough.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie makes writing comparison operators pretty simple.

Comment: _"Bill Gates 43 would be technically less than Bill Gates 44"_ you should test that with the if statement you wrote.  Is it clear why your function returns `false` (**not** less than) for that data?

Answer (score 4):

Here's my version of the comparison:

```
bool person::operator< (const person& b)
{
    if (lastName != b.lastName)
    {
        return lastName < b.lastName;
    }
    if (firstName != b.firstName)
    {
        return firstName < b.firstName;
    }
    return age < b.age;
}
```

If one field is equal to the object, then the next field is compared.
Otherwise the method compares the two fields for less than.

Comment: I like this pattern. Very easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison logic is wrong. You should write something like:

```
bool person::operator<(person b) {
    if (lastName < b.lastName) {
        return true;
    } else if (lastName > b.lastName) {
        return false;
    }

    if (firstName < b.firstName) {
        return true;
    } else if (firstName > b.firstName) {
        return false;
    }

    if (age < b.age) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: No.  This logic will also return incorrect answers.  It will claim a person named `A B` is less than `B A`  **and** it will claim `B A` is less than `A B`.

Comment: @DrewDormann may you please elaborate?

Comment: Use case:  `a.firstName > b.FirstName`.  If this is the case, the function should return false.  No need for further comparisons.  You only need further or deeper compares if the first compare is equal to.

Comment: @WaisKamal the logic in this answer is the same as the logic in the question, except with every `&&` replaced with `||`.  Both are wrong.

Comment: Thanks everyone, now fixed.

Comment: @RetiredNinja good point.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [std::tie](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

It makes writing comparison operators like this very simple and very hard to get wrong.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

struct Person
{
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    int age;

    bool operator<(const Person &other) const
    {
        return std::tie(lastName, firstName, age)
            < std::tie(other.lastName, other.firstName, other.age);
    }
};

void print(const std::string& title, const std::vector<Person> &people)
{
    std::cout << title << "\n";
    for (const Person &person : people)
    {
        std::cout << person.lastName << ", " 
            << person.firstName << ", " 
            << person.age << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Person> people {
        { "Bill", "Gates", 44 },
        { "Gates", "Bill", 44 },
        { "Back", "Gates", 43 },
        { "Front", "Gates", 44 },
        { "Bill", "Gates", 43 },
        { "Gates", "Bill", 43 },
        { "Back", "Gates", 44 },
        { "Front", "Gates", 43 },
    };

    print("Before Sort:", people);
    std::sort(people.begin(), people.end());
    print("After Sort:", people);

    return 0;
}
```

Online example: https://ideone.com/YFnEdB

Output:

```
Before Sort:
Gates, Bill, 44
Bill, Gates, 44
Gates, Back, 43
Gates, Front, 44
Gates, Bill, 43
Bill, Gates, 43
Gates, Back, 44
Gates, Front, 43
After Sort:
Bill, Gates, 43
Bill, Gates, 44
Gates, Back, 43
Gates, Back, 44
Gates, Bill, 43
Gates, Bill, 44
Gates, Front, 43
Gates, Front, 44
```

Comment: And the same for `operator==`: `bool operator==(const Person &other) const { return std::tie(...) == std::tie(...); }`  and `operator!`, `operator>`, etc

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't work for `Bill Gates 43` and `Bill Gates 44`, because you are only using less than operator here and `Bill < Bill` will return false which makes the entire if statement false.

```
bool person::operator < (const person& b) //Always pass your object as reference
{
    if (firstName <= b.firstName && lastName <= b.lastName && age < b.age)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now it will work for the example you gave. But a better way of doing this would be like this considering you want to compare all three attributes in given order.

```
bool person::operator < (const person& b)
{
     if (lastName != b.lastName)
       {
         return lastName < b.lastName;   
       }     
    else if(firstname != b.firstName)
       {
            return firstname < b.firstName;
       }
      else
         return age < b.age;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i misunderstood what you said before. will it work now?

Comment: Best way to find out if something works is to write it up and run it through some tests. If this one fails, it's not immediately obvious. No need for the `return false;` at the end because you can't reach it.